# Markdown Incorrectly Underlining Header

Tags: markdown, roadkill-wiki

We are using the RoadKill Wiki with Markdown as the syntax.  When I create a header using `###Header 3###` I get a header with the correct text size/formatting but I also am getting a separator which spans the entire page width.

According to the documentation [here](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet), only the first and second level headers should have an underline.

Is there something setup incorrectly that is making the headers 3, 4, etc. display with a separator and can this be changed in a style sheet or something.

Comment: On the plain [roadkill demo](http://roadkilldemo.azurewebsites.net/wiki/4138) there is no border-bottom on any heading. Do you use any custom stylesheet? Can you post this stylesheet here?

Are you sure you are [markdown-here](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#headers) with roadkillwiki? markdown-here is a browser extension.

You could try to search in your css for `h3` and and then remove `border-bottom: 1px solid black;` (or similar)

Comment: This sounds like a theme issue (the responsive theme). The .CSS files in the /themes/ folder is the place to change it